# Converting XML to Word Document

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, openxml

I have a word-generated xml file (2007) with the right structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
    <pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
        <!-- content... -->
    </pkg:package>
```

Using Apache Poi, I want to generate the corresponding `XWPFDocument`

```
            try {
                //strXML is the xml content
                File xmlGenFile = new File("./sampleFile.xml");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(xmlGenFile);
                fw.write(strXML);
                fw.close();
                OPCPackage oPack = OPCPackage.open(xmlGenFile);
                XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(oPack);

            } catch (ContentIOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried to use the `OPCPackage.open` method but i am getting `org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException`

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: '.\sampleFile.xml'
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:131)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:246)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:200)
    at tn.com.st2i.service.impl.TemplatingServiceImpl.generateWordDocument(TemplatingServiceImpl.java:105)
    at tn.com.st2i.webscript.RetrieveGeneratedDocumentPost.execute(RetrieveGeneratedDocumentPost.java:79)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:429)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:452)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:491)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:529)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:341)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:157)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:129)
    ... 32 more
```

Obviously, the file exists

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your code AND the stacktrace.

Comment: I edited the post and provided code and stacktrace

Comment: XWPF is for the _new_ docx format, which is a zip file containing xml files in Microsofts OpenDocument format. You have an XML file in what seems to be the old Word format (Word 97-2007), thus you need to use HWPF. All of this is described on the introduction page of the POI Word API [here](https://poi.apache.org/document/index.html). Please read the docs before asking on SO.

Comment: @l4mpi the xml given is in the right format (docx format) as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220(v=office.12).aspx#office2007wordfileformat_word2007documentpackage) and i alredy read the docs before posting and i didn't find a solution for my problem

Comment: @alaeddine.nasri Ok, maybe your XML is conforming to the docx spec, but an XML file is still not a valid docx file as docx files are a zip containing multiple folders and files. Directly quoted from your link, "The file format in Word 2007 consists of a compressed ZIP file, called a package". Simply open any docx file with an archive reader (you might have to rename it to .zip for this to work) to see for yourself.

Comment: yes aboslutely true, but i m talking here about the generated xml file when you choose to save word document as xml

Comment: @alaeddine.nasri well I'm not a Word expert and don't know what kind of format that is, but I do know that POI is for either .doc files (HWPF) or .docx files (XWPF). You're using XWPF, which expects a zip file, but you're passing an xml file. That obviously won't work. Why not just use the original docx instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear from the stacktrace that you are supplying a bare XML file.  A genuine Word 2007 document consists of XML and other files in a ZIP archive.

Comment: I use the generated xml file when choosing the option 'save as xml' in word. In fact I want to add some variables with Freemarker then generating *.docx again

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is Flat OPC XML.

I don't know whether POI can process that, but docx4j (which I work on), can.

See the sample code [ConvertInFlatOpenPackage.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInFlatOpenPackage.java)

By the way, there are also various options for processing "variables" in the Word document itself (ie as opposed to in the Flat OPC representation); the best IMHO being content control data binding.